# How do I get index from clicked row?

Tags: python, sqlite, tkinter, treeview

I'm using a TreeView widget, and I'd like to have an index for the currently clicked row. So far I have something like this:

```py
    self.tree_view_test.bind('<ButtonRelease-1>', self.selectItem)

    def selectItem(self):
        item = self.tree_view_test.selection()[0]
        print(item)
```

But I receiving something like: `I003`, `I004` etc. Do I have to convert it to integer on my own, or there is some better approach for it?

Comment: Try `self.tree_view_test.item(self.tree_view_test.selection()[0],'values')`

Comment: If you wanted index number, then `self.tree_view_test.index(self.tree_view_test.selection()[0])`